# ¿Error en mongodb connection refused?

Tags: linux, mongodb

Buenas queridos amigos de stackoverflow, tengo un error al intentar ejecutar mongo db por medio del comando "mongo" mi sistema operativo es manjaroos y aqui esta el error que me ocurre al ejecutarlo

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-10-25T16:35:29.753-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-10-25T16:35:29.753-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Nota ya le ingrese mongod --repair no me reconoce mongo --repair, y no encuentro en /var/log/mongo/ el archivo que siempre se borra para que funcione no recuerdo si es extension lck.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: intentastes hacer un service mongod status a ver si esta arriba?

Comment: Desconocia funcionaba MongoDB en Manjaro, revisa como iniciarlo en este OS : https://thedarkoznet.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/how-to-install-mongodb-in-manjaro-linux/

Comment: @JackNavaRow el problema es que no me da un status osea me dice : Unit mongo.service could not be found.

Comment: Y qué pasa si haces `sudo service mongod status` o `sudo mongo`?

Comment: dice conexion rechazazda creo que debes verificar el usuario y e password

Comment: @amenadiel Unit mongo.service could not be found. Esto es lo que me sale

Comment: @JackNavaRow ya me meti como root tambien y nada que levanta tampoco!